# How to build Python 3.5.2 from source without root

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, build, centos7

I want to build Python 3.5.2 from source. To make this I need tcl and tk. My configure:

```
./configure 
--prefix=/home/****e/python/python35 \
--with-tcltk-includes="-I/opt/software/tcltk8.6/include" \
--with-tcltk-libs="-L/opt/software/tcltk8.6/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6"
make
```

get compilation error::

```
gcc -pthread -fPIC -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror=declaration-after-statement -DWITH_APPINIT=1 -I./Include -I/home/*****e/python/python35/include -I. -IInclude -I/usr/local/include -I/home/*****e/python/src/Python-3.5.2/Include -I/home/*****e/python/src/Python-3.5.2 -c /home/*****e/python/src/Python-3.5.2/Modules/_tkinter.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/home/*****e/python/src/Python-3.5.2/Modules/_tkinter.o -I/opt/software/tсltk8.5/include
/home/*****e/python/src/Python-3.5.2/Modules/_tkinter.c:49:17: fatal error: tcl.h: No such file or directory
#include <tcl.h>
compilation terminated.

Failed to build these modules:
_tkinter
```

After that I edit file

```
/home/.../Modules/_tkinter.c
```

and write absolute paths

```
#include </opt/software/tсltk8.6/include/tcl.h>
#include </opt/software/tсltk8.6/include/tk.h>
```

As result, compilation goes on, but stuck on this

```
-o Modules/getbuildinfo.o ./Modules/getbuildinfo.c
gcc -pthread   -o Programs/_freeze_importlib Programs/_freeze_importlib.o Modules/getbuildinfo.o Parser/acceler.o Parser/grammar1.o Parser/listnode.o Parser/node.o Parser/parser.o Parser/bitset.o Parser/metagrammar.o Parser/firstsets.o Parser/grammar.o Parser/pgen.o Parser/myreadline.o Parser/parsetok.o Parser/tokenizer.o Objects/abstract.o Objects/accu.o Objects/boolobject.o Objects/bytes_methods.o Objects/bytearrayobject.o Objects/bytesobject.o Objects/cellobject.o Objects/classobject.o Objects/codeobject.o Objects/complexobject.o Objects/descrobject.o Objects/enumobject.o Objects/exceptions.o Objects/genobject.o Objects/fileobject.o Objects/floatobject.o Objects/frameobject.o Objects/funcobject.o Objects/iterobject.o Objects/listobject.o Objects/longobject.o Objects/dictobject.o Objects/odictobject.o Objects/memoryobject.o Objects/methodobject.o Objects/moduleobject.o Objects/namespaceobject.o Objects/object.o Objects/obmalloc.o Objects/capsule.o Objects/rangeobject.o Objects/setobject.o Objects/sliceobject.o Objects/structseq.o Objects/tupleobject.o Objects/typeobject.o Objects/unicodeobject.o Objects/unicodectype.o Objects/weakrefobject.o Python/_warnings.o Python/Python-ast.o Python/asdl.o Python/ast.o Python/bltinmodule.o Python/ceval.o Python/compile.o Python/codecs.o Python/dynamic_annotations.o Python/errors.o Python/frozenmain.o Python/future.o Python/getargs.o Python/getcompiler.o Python/getcopyright.o Python/getplatform.o Python/getversion.o Python/graminit.o Python/import.o Python/importdl.o Python/marshal.o Python/modsupport.o Python/mystrtoul.o Python/mysnprintf.o Python/peephole.o Python/pyarena.o Python/pyctype.o Python/pyfpe.o Python/pyhash.o Python/pylifecycle.o Python/pymath.o Python/pystate.o Python/pythonrun.o Python/pytime.o Python/random.o Python/structmember.o Python/symtable.o Python/sysmodule.o Python/traceback.o Python/getopt.o Python/pystrcmp.o Python/pystrtod.o Python/pystrhex.o Python/dtoa.o Python/formatter_unicode.o Python/fileutils.o Python/dynload_shlib.o   Python/thread.o Modules/config.o Modules/getpath.o Modules/main.o Modules/gcmodule.o  Modules/_threadmodule.o  Modules/signalmodule.o  Modules/posixmodule.o  Modules/errnomodule.o  Modules/pwdmodule.o  Modules/_sre.o  Modules/_codecsmodule.o  Modules/_weakref.o  Modules/_functoolsmodule.o  Modules/_operator.o  Modules/_collectionsmodule.o  Modules/itertoolsmodule.o  Modules/atexitmodule.o  Modules/_stat.o  Modules/timemodule.o  Modules/_localemodule.o  Modules/_iomodule.o Modules/iobase.o Modules/fileio.o Modules/bytesio.o Modules/bufferedio.o Modules/textio.o Modules/stringio.o  Modules/zipimport.o  Modules/faulthandler.o  Modules/_tracemalloc.o Modules/hashtable.o  Modules/symtablemodule.o  Modules/_tkinter.o Modules/tkappinit.o  Modules/xxsubtype.o -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -L/opt/software/tcltk8.6/lib -ltk8.6.8 -ltcl8.6.8 -lX11   -lm  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltk8.6.8
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltcl8.6.8
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

what shoul I do in this case and why it looks tcl and tk in `/usr/bin/ld`

tcl and tk installed in:

```
/opt/software/tcltk8.6
```

Python's sourse in:

```
~/python/src/Python-3.5.2
```

Comment: The errors did not mean the TCL/TK libs were searched in /usr/bin/ld directory.  It means the program /usr/bin/ld raised the error that it could not find the libs.  Use `./configure --help` to find which option to specify the path to the libs.

Comment: @acw1668 - Thanks a lot! I'm new in Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution. You should install all packages in common directory

sqlite3 installation:

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/python/installation/homedir
make -j && make install
```

tcl installation:

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/python/installation/homedir
make -j && make install
```

tk installation:

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/python/installation/homedir --with-tcl=/path/to/tcl/source/tcl8.6.8/unix
make -j && make install
```

Before Python installation you should set environment variables:

```
export LD_LIBRARY=/path/to/python/installation/homedir/lib
export TK_LIBRARY=/path/to/python/installation/homedir/lib
```

Edit `setup.py` file and add path to sqlite3 lib to array:

```
sqlite_inc_paths = [ '/usr/include',
                 '/usr/include/sqlite',
                 '/usr/include/sqlite3',
                 '/usr/local/include',
                 '/usr/local/include/sqlite',
                 '/usr/local/include/sqlite3',
                 '/path/to/python/installation/homedir/include',
                 ]
```

And Python installation:

```
./configure \
--prefix=path/to/python/installation/homedir \
make -j && make install
```

After that all should make correct.

Answer (score 0):

The very long solution by @[Prahvessor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6272872/prahvessor) isn't needed, just change the build file `Modules/Setup` as such:

### `Modules/Setup`

```diff
diff --git a/Modules/Setup b/Modules/Setup
index 8fe7951278..dabdcc6212 100644
--- a/Modules/Setup
+++ b/Modules/Setup
@@ -300,3 +300,7 @@ PYTHONPATH=$(COREPYTHONPATH)
 #
 # _sqlite3 _tkinter _curses pyexpat
 # _codecs_jp _codecs_kr _codecs_tw unicodedata
+#
+*disabled*
+
+_tkinter
```